# What is the name for the phenomenon where an English verb that takes a clausal complement either does or does not mark the infinitive with "to"?

Tags: syntax, english, terminology, grammar, complement

> Let them go home.
> *Let them to go home.
>
> *Allow them go home.
> Allow them to go home.
>
> Make them go home.
> *Make them to go home.
>
> *Force them go home.
> Force them to go home.

What is the reason that "let" and "make" don't take "to" before the infinitive and "allow" and "force" do? And what is this phenomenon called?

Comment: It's governed by the matrix verb. Modals don't take _to_, small verbs like _let_ and _make_ (which are almost bleached of meaning and effectively express a category that would be morphological in some other languages), and special constructions like _go figure_ or _come sit by me_ don't take _to_. Much like the subject marker _for_ largely disappears from infinitive clauses (along with the subject NP), the verb marker _to_ is on the way out, but slowly. Most of the time it's contracted to schwa in speech anyway. Eventually that schwa will be interpreted as epenthetic.

Comment: The auxiliary verb “to do” used in questions and negative forms also governs the following infinitive without “to”: in _Do you **hear** me? Don't **go** there!_ “hear” and “go” are infinitives.

Answer (score 4):

It's called [subcategorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcategorization): particular words (not just verbs) allow or require particular words or structures for their arguments.

There may be some heuristics for determining the allowable structures, but in the end they are arbitrary lexical properties of the words in question.